# how to test another method in my main method in java

Tags: java, count

I'm practicing to test my method (it is to count the number of vowels) in my main function. 
I was wondering how I can implement my code here? Is there also flaw in my codes?

```
public class MethodPractice{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        numVowels(howcanitesthere);    //i know this is wrong, just trying smth..

    }

    public static int numVowels(String s){

        String text = ("");
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < text.length() ;i ++){
            char c = text.charAt(i);

            if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Comment: You could.. pass it a string? I don't understand what you're struggling with.

Comment: I have no clue what you're actually asking us to help with. What do you want the input and the result of this test to be?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can format your question so the code is more readible; consult the [Markdown Help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or the [formatting reference provided when you're editing your question](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e29f4970b-pi).

Comment: i want a user to put inputs in words and get the number of vowels as a result.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

- You can pass through a parameter from the command line, or
- You can pass a bunch of hard-coded arguments, and check the answers.

Here is an example:

Command-line arguments:

```
if (args.length == 1) {
    System.out.println(numVowels(args[0]));
}
```

Hardcoded strings:

```
if (numVowels("hello") == 2) {
    System.out.println("OK");
} else {
    System.out.println("wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(numVowels("A test string"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numVowels("test string");
```

...that's all!

But you have to change `System.out.println(count);` to `return count;` in your function for it to work. Otherwise you will get an error.

Once you do this, try putting this in your main method:

```
System.out.println(numVowels("test string"));
```